# Does NDB auto-batching work with caching disabled?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

The NDB docs mention auto-batching several times but there isn't a section that describes exactly when and how it works.  I'd like to know if auto-batching is dependant on NDB's default enabled [caching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache).

I wrote an app long before Py27 and NDB were available.  It has custom caching already incorporated which uses memcache and cross-request instance caching.  I plan to migrate to NDB to take advantage of the cleaner [async](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async) capabilities but disable all the NDB internal caching.  I'd like to know if I optimize my app for auto-batching will it still work?  Or since I'm disabling all the caching is that going to interfere with the batching mechanism?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about disabling internal caching, auto-batching will work independently.

Be sure to use an annotation as @ndb.toplevel. When running async operations, you want to make sure they are run before the main thread finalizes, and an @ndb.toplevel annotation will take care of that.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async